# Why can't we rule out negative variances when using gerber statistic for creating the covariance matrix?

Tags: matrices, variance, covariance

I recently read that one problem with gerber statistic is that we cannot guarantee the statistic matrix to be positive semi-definite. Why is that the case and how is it different from normal covariance matrix calculation?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.